# GAMS: card operator over subset

Tags: subset, operator-keyword, gams-math

I am trying to model a Cross Dock Problem. It has the following sets:

j for Outbound Trucks,

s for sorting stations and

l for Outbound Docks.

And moreover there is a binary variable z(j,s), which is one, if Outbound Truck j is assigned to sorting station s.

Before calculation you have to assign the Outbound Docks to the Sorting Stations. For this I defined a subset k(s,l). My example looks like this:

```
Sets

j      /J1*J27/
s      /S1*S4/
l      /L1*L30/
;

Sets  k(s,l)

        /S1.(L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6)
         S2.(L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12)
         S3.(L13,L14,L15,L16,L17,L18,L19,L20)
         S4.(L21,L22,L23,L24,L25,L26,L27,L28,L29,L30)/
```

The Problem I have is to model the following equation:

[image: This restriction says, that you cannot assign more Outbound Trucks to Sorting Station s, than there are Outbound Docks assigned to this Station. L(s) is the amount of Outbound Docks assigned to Sorting Station s.]

How do I model this? I tried it this way:

equation(s)..        `sum(j, z(j,s)) =l= card(k);`

but it doesn't work, because 'card(k)' doesn't represent the amount of Outbound Docks assigned to Sorting Station s. So my question is, if it is possible to model the card operator over subsets?

Or does anyone know another possible way to model this equation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all k is not at subset it is a multidimensional set.

No, it is not possible to use card of a multidimensional set.

It seems that you wish to calculate how many outbound docks, there is for each sorting station. The constraint should be formulated as:

equation(s)..  sum(j, z(j,s)) =l= sum(l$k(s,l),1);

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I found another way to model it.